# HTML form input to update paragraph

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a multi line input text box in a webpage and want all the entered text to update another area of text in the page. How would I be best to achieve this? At the moment, I have it that when you submit the form, php writes the input to a small text file which is then embedded in the page.

But, do I need to sanitize this so that people don't inject html. Also, do I need to make it add `<p>...</p>` tags for every line in the input box?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to have it saved on the page for subsequent views by the same user, multiple users, or just for that instance of the page?

Comment: Does the updated text need to be stored in a database, or accessed for future use?

Comment: the input is stored to a small text file so that whenever anyone else views another page, it shows the message. So it should be stored until updated again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do depends on your requirements. You should definitely use `htmlspecialchars()` or `strip_tags()` to nullify any errant HTML. After that you can simply use `nl2br()` to insert some `<BR>` to space everything or you can `explode()` your string and add `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the update is being saved (just that instance, permanentlyfor that user, or permanently for all users), the options range from Javascript/Jquery simply updating that other text area to AJAX calls to a php backend script that sanitizes and saves the update.

For the `<p>`, you can use Javascript to split() based on newlines and then add a each element as a `<p>text</p>` using a for loop. The concept should work with any language.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are trying to accomplish. is this a type of BLOG entry where the text that was already there remains and what you have typed is appended? is all the text being replaced? will this text be needed anywhere else besides on this page (database, recalled at a later time?)

once we have a few of those questions answered we can move forward :)

Also, what technology are you using? pure HTML, Javascript, PHP, ASP? that will help determin the best method for what you're trying to accomplish. (I did see php, just wondering what our options are)

elaborate and we'll figure it out :)... This is a simple AJAX call to load a text file into a div ... the premise should work (if i got the code right off the top of my head) ....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="media">
        </div>
        <form id="myform" method="POST">
            <input type="textarea" name="MyParagraph"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Change Text" onclick='$.get("SterilizeMyText.php",{ nbRandom: Math.random() }, function(data){ $("#media").html(data); });'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

you can change the onclick to be a php file that will take form variables ($_REQUEST['blah']) ahd then output the cleansed text if you like.

Comment: it is not a blog, the new text will replace the entire text file. it is like an update section, so someone who is not computer literate can post a message on the website without having to touch html. Was going to use php, but if javascript is required, will give it a go! thanks for the snippet. will see if i can get my head around it!

Answer (score 0):

To sanitize your input, please use http://htmlpurifier.org/ over strip_tags().